# Why ubuntu's Ambiance GTK3 theme has a settings.ini file that embeds CSS?

Tags: css, ubuntu, themes, gtk3

Reading about how theming works in GTK3 via CSS I've started to play with my default theme in Ubuntu 13.04, which is called Ambiance. Its source is in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/`.

Now the interesting thing is, I tried to change a colour in the file `gtk-main.css` under this directory (inside a @define-color statement), and to my surprise the change didn't take effect even after rebooting the computer.

Later, I found out that there is a `settings.ini` file (in the same folder) with this contents:

```
[Settings]
gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#ffffff\nbg_color:#f2f1f0\ntooltip_bg_color:#000000\nselected_bg_color:#ffffff\ntext_color:#3C3C3C\nfg_color:#4c4c4c\ntooltip_fg_color:#ffffff\nselected_fg_color:#ffffff\nlink_color:#DD4814\nbg_color_dark:#3c3b37\nfg_color_dark:#dfdbd2"
gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
```

WTF, so the contents of `gtk-main.css` are embedded there in the `settings.ini` file inside the variable gtk-color-scheme. Changing this variable **does change** the colour in my current Gtk theme.

So then I have some questions about this:

- Why this redundancy? (They could have removed the file gtk-main.css to avoid confusions.)
- Is this a ubuntu-specific hack? If not, then where is this documented? I didn't find any info about this in the Gnome website.
- What's the purpose of this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a way to override @define-color rules, as mentioned [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkCssProvider.html#gtkcssprovider-rules), and later explained [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-color-scheme).

Answer (score 0):

Short and concise: You would alter the theme.

> How would you revert to the original values, when you would have edited those?

**You could not**,  but if your alteration goes into the `.ini`, it can be reset to the values of the `.css` file with this very `.css` file.